# Parse Array hashes in new object with ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, object, hash

I am struggling with some arrays with hashes inside. I want to parse them into a new object but have no idea how to do this.

Here is the data:

```
[
  {
    "name"  => "itemHref",
    "value" => "https://192.168.75.145:8281/api/workflows/16da1fa1-7c8b-4602-8d53-17fc5e1fa3ff/"
  },
  {
    "name"  => "id",
    "value" => "16da1fa1-7c8b-4602-8d53-17fc5e1fa3ff"
  },
  {
    "name"  => "categoryName",
    "value" => "FinanzInformatik"
  },
  {
    "name"  => "canExecute",
    "value" => "true"
  },
  {
    "name"  => "categoryHref",
    "value" => "https://192.168.75.145:8281/api/catalog/System/WorkflowCategory/ff8080813b90a145013b90cac51b0006/"
  },
  {
    "name"  => "description",
    "value" => "bekommt alle VMs"
  },
  {
    "name"  => "name",
    "value" => "getAllVms"
  },
  {
    "name"  => "type",
    "value" => "Workflow"
  },
  {
    "name"  => "canEdit",
    "value" => "true"
  }
]
```

And, here is my code:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

class Workflow
  def initialize(itemHref, id, categoryName, canExecute, categoryHref, description, name, type, canEdit)
    @itemHref = itemHref
    @id = id
    @categoryName = categoryName
    @canExecute = canExecute
    @categoryHref = categoryHref
    @description = description
    @name = name
    @type = type
    @canEdit = canEdit
  end
end

json_string = RestClient.get( "http://vcoadmin:vcoadmin@192.168.75.145:8280/api/workflows", :content_type => 'application/json', :accept => 'application/json')
parsed = JSON.parse(json_string)

parsed.each do |a, b|
 if(b.class == Array)
  b.flatten.each do |c|
   p c['attributes']
   #c['attributes'].each
  {
    |f| p f['name'], f['value'] }
  end
 end
end
```

How do I put the hash value into the object? I think about something based on the 'name' which is the identifier for the value.

Any ideas?

Comment: The array with hashes is the output of the parsed.each... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the order of attributes shouldn't be changed:

```
Workflow.new(*parsed.map {|attr| attr['value']})
```

Comment: So easy? Damn! But I receive: json_parser.rb:30:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError) In which line should I include that? The parsed variable is available before all the each stuff.

Comment: p parsed.map {|attr| attr['value']} produces this error also.

Comment: Ensure that json response you've got is an array of hashes.

Comment: You´re right. It was an Array with an Array of Hashes :) Here is the code which works for me: parsed.each do |a, b|
 if(b.class == Array)
  b.flatten.each do |c|
   Workflow.new(*c['attributes'].map { |attr| attr['value'] })
  end
 end
end

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a PORO that can be initialized with a hash.  So then you are able to pass your hash directly in to creating the workflow.

An example of this is can be seen: http://pullmonkey.com/2008/01/06/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-a-class-object/